# Generating PDF from HTML giving unwanted space due table inside table

Tags: html, css, pdf

```html
<html>
    <head>

   <style>
   body {
  margin: 0;
 }
   table{
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
   }
   thead.t1{
   background: #dac8c8;
   }
   table td , table th{
   padding:10px;
   }
   table{
   margin-top:20px;
   }
   thead.t2{
   background: #dcdcdc;
   }
 @media print{
 @page {
  size: A4 landscape;
 }
  }
 
 table { page-break-inside:auto }
 tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
 thead { display:table-header-group }
 @media print{
  table {page-break-after:always}
 } 



   
   </style>
   
  </head>

 <body class="" style="width:1070px; margin:0 auto;">
 
 
 <div style="height:300px; width:100%; background:#ccc; border-bottom:2px solid #000;">
 </div>
  <table class="splitForPrint table-rc1 ">
   <thead class="t1">
   <tr>
    <th> column1 </th>
    <th> column2 </th>
    <th> column3 </th>
    <th> column4 </th>
    <th> column5 </th>
    <th> column6 </th>
    <th> column7 </th>
    <th> column8 </th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="8" class="">
     <div class=" table-block">
      
      <table>
       <thead class="t2">
        <tr>
         <td> column thead 1 </td>
         <td> column thead 2 </td>
         <td> column thead 3 </td>
         <td> column thead 4 </td>
         <td> column thead 5 </td>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       
       
       <tbody>
       
        <tr>
        <td> column td1 </td>
        <td> column td2 </td>
        <td> column td3 </td>
        <td> column td4 </td>
        <td> column td5 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> column td1 </td>
        <td> column td2 </td>
        <td> column td3 </td>
        <td> column td4 </td>
        <td> column td5 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> column td1 </td>
        <td> column td2 </td>
        <td> column td3 </td>
        <td> column td4 </td>
        <td> column td5 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> column td1 </td>
        <td> column td2 </td>
        <td> column td3 </td>
        <td> column td4 </td>
        <td> column td5 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> column td1 </td>
        <td> column td2 </td>
        <td> column td3 </td>
        <td> column td4 </td>
        <td> column td5 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> column td1 </td>
        <td> column td2 </td>
        <td> column td3 </td>
        <td> column td4 </td>
        <td> column td5 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> column td1 </td>
        <td> column td2 </td>
        <td> column td3 </td>
        <td> column td4 </td>
        <td> column td5 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> column td1 </td>
        <td> column td2 </td>
        <td> column td3 </td>
        <td> column td4 </td>
        <td> column td5 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> column td1 </td>
        <td> column td2 </td>
        <td> column td3 </td>
        <td> column td4 </td>
        <td> column td5 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> column td1 </td>
        <td> column td2 </td>
        <td> column td3 </td>
        <td> column td4 </td>
        <td> column td5 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> column td1 </td>
        <td> column td2 </td>
        <td> column td3 </td>
        <td> column td4 </td>
        <td> column td5 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> column td1 </td>
        <td> column td2 </td>
        <td> column td3 </td>
        <td> column td4 </td>
        <td> column td5 </td>
       </tr>
     
       
       
       </tbody>
      
      </table>
     
     
 
     </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    
  </table>
 </body>
 
</html>
```

Here I have HTML code which is not coming proper when I generate PDF.
What I want table should start from first page not from second page while generating PDF in landscape mode also thead having class "t2" should repeat in every page as data increase in table inside "table-block" div.

[image]

Comment: You have specified a < div style="height:300px; width:100%; background:#ccc; border-bottom:2px solid #000;">
 </div  >    what is use of that?Try to use mm instead of px,give me a min I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>

      <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
    }
      table{
        width: 100%;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: center;
      }
      thead.t1{
      background: #dac8c8;
      }
      table td , table th{
      padding:1mm;
      }
      table{
      margin-top:1mm;
      }
      thead.t2{
      background: #dcdcdc;
      }
    @media print{
    @page {
        size: A4 landscape;
    }
  }
    
    table { page-break-inside:auto }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group }
    @media print{
        table {page-break-after:always}
    }   



      
      </style>
      
     </head>

    <body class="" style="width:1070px; margin:0 auto;">
    
    
<div style="height:300px; width:100%; background:#ccc; border-bottom:2px solid #000;">
    </div>
        <table class="splitForPrint table-rc1 ">
            <thead class="t1">
            <tr>
                <th> column1 </th>
                <th> column2 </th>
                <th> column3 </th>
                <th> column4 </th>
                <th> column5 </th>
                <th> column6 </th>
                <th> column7 </th>
                <th> column8 </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td colspan="8" class="">
                    <div class=" table-block">
                        
                        <table>
                            <thead class="t2">
                                <tr>
                                    <td> column thead 1 </td>
                                    <td> column thead 2 </td>
                                    <td> column thead 3 </td>
                                    <td> column thead 4 </td>
                                    <td> column thead 5 </td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            
                            
                            <tbody>
                            
                                <tr>
                                <td> column td1 </td>
                                <td> column td2 </td>
                                <td> column td3 </td>
                                <td> column td4 </td>
                                <td> column td5 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> column td1 </td>
                                <td> column td2 </td>
                                <td> column td3 </td>
                                <td> column td4 </td>
                                <td> column td5 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> column td1 </td>
                                <td> column td2 </td>
                                <td> column td3 </td>
                                <td> column td4 </td>
                                <td> column td5 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> column td1 </td>
                                <td> column td2 </td>
                                <td> column td3 </td>
                                <td> column td4 </td>
                                <td> column td5 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> column td1 </td>
                                <td> column td2 </td>
                                <td> column td3 </td>
                                <td> column td4 </td>
                                <td> column td5 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> column td1 </td>
                                <td> column td2 </td>
                                <td> column td3 </td>
                                <td> column td4 </td>
                                <td> column td5 </td>
                            </tr>
                            
                                <td> column td1 </td>
                                <td> column td2 </td>
                                <td> column td3 </td>
                                <td> column td4 </td>
                                <td> column td5 </td>
                            </tr>
                    
                            
                            
                            </tbody>
                        
                        </table>
                    
                    
    
                    </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                
        </table>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

I have used mm instead of px and the table is display in the first page.

Comment: First: please do not comment this 
<!--<div style="height:300px; width:100%; background:#ccc; border-bottom:2px solid #000;">
 </div>!-->


Second: Try with the same number of tr because if number of tr get increase it automatically adapt the space.

Comment: When I tried to print the page without commenting div also, it was showing the table  starting from the first page.Could you please explain further?

Comment: try with 6 tr in tbody it will give you different result

Comment: Updated the codes,Please check it.Let me know if there is any issues.

Comment: May be I am not able to explain it properly let me try again.

The rows that we are trying to print falls under the scenario where the number of rows overflow the first page but can fit  in the second page. In this scenario the entire list is moved to the second page leaving a space behind in the first page.
In this case if you take 20 tr it will again not come properly

Comment: I tried the same with adding more than 20 trs, I was not leaving any spaces.I'm using chrome and trying to preview before printing.Can you try the above codes in chrome?

Comment: I tried but not work keep total number of tr equals to 20